# EXCEPTION: No Directive annotation found on RiskService in angular2 application

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am trying to build an angular 2 application using typescript in visual studio 2015 application. I am using angular release candidate 1.

I have created a risk.service component which will provide data to my view. However I am getting the following error message in the console of my browser while running the application.

EXCEPTION: No Directive annotation found on RiskService.

**My folder structure**

[image]

**risk.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { IRisk } from './risk';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class RiskService {

    getRisks(): IRisk[] {
        return [

            {
                "riskId": 1,
                "reference": "HISC9308336",
                "insuredName": "SA 84161",
                "inceptionDate": "March 19, 2016",
                "riskType": "Quote",
                "status": "Indication",
                "grossPremium": 100,
                "allocatedTo": "Broker User",
                "allocatedCompany": "Broker"
            },
            {
                "riskId": 2,
                "reference": "HISC9308340",
                "insuredName": "Upper Loi",
                "inceptionDate": "April 25, 2016",
                "riskType": "Quote",
                "status": "Indication",
                "grossPremium": 312.22,
                "allocatedTo": "Andy Marples",
                "allocatedCompany": "Broker"
            },
            {
                "riskId": 3,
                "reference": "HISC9308342",
                "insuredName": "Test",
                "inceptionDate": "April 28, 2016",
                "riskType": "Quote",
                "status": "Indication",
                "grossPremium": 312.2,
                "allocatedTo": "Broker User",
                "allocatedCompany": "Broker"
            },
            {
                "riskId": 4,
                "reference": "HISC9308344",
                "insuredName": "Test",
                "inceptionDate": "April 29, 2016",
                "riskType": "Quote",
                "status": "Quoted",
                "grossPremium": 444.12,
                "allocatedTo": "Broker User",
                "allocatedCompany": "Broker"
            },
            {
                "riskId": 5,
                "reference": "HISC9308345",
                "insuredName": "Test",
                "inceptionDate": "May 02, 2016",
                "riskType": "Quote",
                "status": "Indication",
                "grossPremium": 423.82,
                "allocatedTo": "Broker User",
                "allocatedCompany": "Broker"
            }
            ,
            {
                "riskId": 6,
                "reference": "HISC9308340",
                "insuredName": "Upper Loi",
                "inceptionDate": "April 25, 2016",
                "riskType": "Quote",
                "status": "Indication",
                "grossPremium": 312.22,
                "allocatedTo": "Andy Marples",
                "allocatedCompany": "Broker"
            },
            {
                "riskId": 7,
                "reference": "HISC9308342",
                "insuredName": "Test",
                "inceptionDate": "April 28, 2016",
                "riskType": "Quote",
                "status": "Indication",
                "grossPremium": 312.22,
                "allocatedTo": "Broker User",
                "allocatedCompany": "Broker"
            },
            {
                "riskId": 8,
                "reference": "HISC9308344",
                "insuredName": "Test",
                "inceptionDate": "April 29, 2016",
                "riskType": "Quote",
                "status": "Quoted",
                "grossPremium": 444.12,
                "allocatedTo": "Broker User",
                "allocatedCompany": "Broker"
            },
            {
                "riskId": 9,
                "reference": "HISC9308345",
                "insuredName": "Test",
                "inceptionDate": "May 02, 2016",
                "riskType": "Quote",
                "status": "Indication",
                "grossPremium": 423.82,
                "allocatedTo": "Broker User",
                "allocatedCompany": "Broker"
            }

        ];
    }
}
```

**risk-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IRisk } from './risk';
import { RiskService } from './risk.service';
import { DataTable, Column } from 'primeng/primeng';
import {Header} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {Footer} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {Paginator} from 'primeng/primeng';


@Component({
    selector: 'rm-risks',
    directives: [DataTable, Column, Header, Footer, Paginator, RiskService],
    templateUrl: '/app/components/risks/risk-list.component.html'
    })

export class RiskListComponent implements OnInit {
    pageTitle: string = 'Risk List';

    risks: IRisk[];

    constructor(private _riskService: RiskService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.risks = this._riskService.getRisks();
    }
};
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RiskListComponent } from './components/risks/risk-list.component';
import { DataTable, Column } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { RiskService } from './components/risks/risk.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    providers: [RiskService],
    template: `
    <div>
        <h1>{{pageTitle}}</h1>
          <rm-risks> </rm-risks> 
     </div>
     ` ,
    directives: [RiskListComponent, DataTable, Column]

})

export class AppComponent {
    pageTitle: string = 'Test UK Trader'; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In risk-list.component.ts

Since RiskService isn't a directive, it shouldnt be listed here:

```
directives: [DataTable, Column, Header, Footer, Paginator, **RiskService**]
```

Instead it should be imported like this

```
import { RiskService } from './risk.service';
directives: [DataTable, Column, Header, Footer, Paginator]
providers: [RiskService]
```

Comment: I still get the same error after removing RiskService from the header. Also I get error while writing the the import statement that you have given me. It doesn't accept that path. It accepts path ./risk.service. I probably think because the service is under the risks folder which is the root for the service file as well. But I still seem to have the same Exception that I have mentioned in my post above

Comment: thats correct i edited service path.. what version of angular are you on?

Comment: angular 2 release candidate 1

Comment: did you try this? import { RiskService } from './risk.service';
directives: [DataTable, Column, Header, Footer, Paginator]
providers: [RiskService]

Comment: Yes I tried putting the provider attribute in the risk-list.component.ts as well .Same error

Comment: Did you remove it from directives list here too?? You probably might have, but i want to double check: directives: [DataTable, Column, Header, Footer, Paginator, **RiskService**]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113050/discussion-between-tom-and-som).

Comment: Thanks Som for pointing out the missing code. Basically I missed adding   "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.1" in my Package.json file. Also included the following in my main.ts where I bootstrap my angular components import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from  '@angular/http'; bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, RiskService]).catch(err => console.error(err));

Answer (score 0):

You shoud define your services into the `providers` attribute of components:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'rm-risks',
  directives: [DataTable, Column, Header, Footer, Paginator],
  providers: [RiskService],
  templateUrl: '/app/components/risks/risk-list.component.html'
})
export class RiskListComponent implements OnInit {
  (...)
}
```

or when you bootstrap your application:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [RiskService]);
```

Comment: I have already specified the service in the provider attribute of my app.component class. That's my root component of the application

Comment: So you don't need to specify it again... Do you have any error by simply removing it from the `directives` attribute of your components?

Comment: I get this error even I remove or mention it in the directives attribute. EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): No Directive annotation found on RiskService

Comment: I think that there is another place where it's set :-)